# Convert reduceByKey from Spark to Flink

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-flink

How can I convert this sample scala spark code to apache flink?

```
reduceByKey( (x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, ( (x._2) ++ y._2) ) )
```

I realized that `reduceByKey` doen't exists in flink, but it shows what I am trying to achieve.

Thank you any help!

Comment: maybe with .groupBy(0).reduce() ?

Answer (score 5):

Unlike Spark, Flink does not need key value pairs to execute reduce, join and coGroup operations. It can execute them directly on any types such as POJOs, tuples or a user type. What you have to provide to Flink is the field on which it has to group. This can be either be a function which extracts the key, a logical index or the name of the field. When you then call the `reduce` operation, then the whole object is given to the reduce function and not only the value part.

So assuming you have a `input: DataSet[(K, (T, List[U]))]` with `K` being the key type, then your reduce function would look like:

```scala
input.groupBy(0).reduce{
  (left: (K, (T, List[U])), right: (K, (T, List[U]))) =>
    val (key, (leftValue1, leftValue2)) = left
    val (_, (rightValue1, rightValue2)) = right

    (key, (leftValue1 + rightValue1, leftValue2 ++ rightValue2))
}
```

For the sake of understanding, I've also provided the type annotations to the anonymous function. This is not necessary though.

#### Update

This is the solution for Humberto's specific use case assuming that the input field consists of rows with 3 entries, whitespace separated and the third entry is an integer:

```
val input = env.readCsvFile[(String, String, Int)](filePath, lineDelimiter = "\n", fieldDelimiter = " ")

val result = input
  .map (element => (element._1, element._3, Map(element._2 -> element._3)))
  .groupBy(0)
  .reduce{
    (left, right) =>
      val (key, left1, left2) = left
      val (_, right1, right2) = right

      (key, left1 + right1, left2 ++ right2)
  }
```

Comment: tks for trying help me. The complete line in Spark code is: val target = words.map(line => (line(0), (line(2).toInt, Map(line(1) -> line(2).toInt)))).reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, ((x._2) ++ y._2))) I have no idea how rewrite it in Flink. I'm newbie.

Comment: @HumbertoMoura, what's the type of `line`? Is that an array of strings?

Comment: lines are lines of words   read from a text file using  readTextFile()    val sc = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment   
val input = sc.readTextFile("file:///Users/humberto/Documents/mini.1")
val words = input.map(line => line.split(" "))  val target = words.map(line => (line(0), (line(2).toInt ...

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your specific use case.

Comment: it worked this line of code. But, with this change, unfortunately generate  more 3 erros. All my original code is here: http://humbertomoura.com.br/flink/Minimantics.txt and my best try with yours tips : http://humbertomoura.com.br/flink/Flink.txt   I really need convert this code, because I'm using in others experiments of big data. Thanks a lot any help.

Answer (score 1):

`reduceByKey` basically apply the function `(V, V) => V` on the values of `(K, V)` key-value pairs grouped by key. An equivalent "plain scala" implementation of:

```
reduceByKey( (v1, v2) => (v1._1 + v2._1, ( (v1._2) ++ v2._2) ) )
```

could be:

```
groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.values.reduce((v1, v2) => ...))
```

(if I got it right)

---

A possible flink implementation could be:

```
groupBy(0).reduce { (v1, v2) => (v1._1 + v2._1, ( (v1._2) ++ v2._2) ) }
```

group by key, then reduce by a function applied on the **values**.

---

**EDIT** after @Till explanation

> When you then call the reduce operation, then the whole object is
>   given to the reduce function and not only the value part.

```
groupBy(0).map(_._2).reduce { (v1, v2) => (v1._1 + v2._1, ( (v1._2) ++ v2._2) ) }

// or the ugly:
groupBy(0).reduce { (kv1, kv2) => (kv1._2._1 + kv2._2._1, ( (kv1._2._2) ++ kv2._2._2) ) }
```

Comment: So I try:  val target = words.map(line => (line(0), (line(2).toInt, Map((line(1) -> line(2).toInt))))).groupBy(0).reduce { (x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, ( (x._2) ++  y._2) ) }
    but it gives me an error in "(x._2) ++":  "value ++ is not a member of (Int, 
  scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int])". Really, I don't know why. Tks

Comment: Thanks for help, but still gets sintaxe error. The complete original line in Spark  is: val target = words.map(line => (line(0), (line(2).toInt, Map(line(1) -> line(2).toInt)))).reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, ((x._2) ++ y._2))) and I tried with the new code, but the sintaxe error persists.